# Maximum expiration date of an Azure Service Principal credential password?

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id, credentials

If you assign a Azure AD Service Principal to Azure (e.g. Azure Container Registry), what is the maximum expiration date of the credential password for that service principal?

Is it 1 year?  Can you set it to 10 years?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a service principal in the portal you can specify an expiry of 1 or 2 years or never.

[image]

If you use the CLI or PowerShell there is a years paramter that allows you to specific a number of years, it defaults to 1.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!